# Application working fine in iOS 8 device but crashing in iOS 7 devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have developed application using Xcode 6 which is using **auto layout and size classes** . It is working fine in iOS 8 devices but there is problem while running application on iOS 7 devices. In one view controller the application is crashing with the following exception :

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIView 0x7916a9c0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key keyPath.'
```

I have checked all the connection in connection inspector ,those all are clean. Please suggest some solution to overcome this problem .

Comment: looks like its not related to os or connections. you are setting value to UIView, which I think you might have thought of Dictionary.

Comment: there is nothing to do with the dictionary , this problem lies in storyboard

Comment: I had similar problem when I was copying some buttons from one view to another. They stayed connected in IB but still I needed to reconnect them.

Comment: Remove all IBOutlets and re-connect them.

Comment: @Wongzigii: I am getting same exception after removing all the connections.

Comment: `<UIView 0x7916a9c0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:` Also check the class identifier for the view you attached to.

Comment: @V-Xtreme, as others said issue should be with IBOutlet, remove your existing app in  your iOS 8 device and  clean and run in your iOS 8 device, you should get the same error as you see in iOS 7.

Answer (score 1):

This is normally related to a deleted IBOutlet. Check your Storyboard/Nibs outlets and see if there anything marked with an "!": it means the corresponding outlet was removed.

Comment: I have already checked all the connections . I am not seeing ! mark before any connection. so seems like the connections are clean . also same storyboard working fine in iOS 8 devices